# Can't access to Blenderkit with 3.0 version

Tags: add-on, blenderkit

Did you guys also lose access to Blenderkit with the 3.0 version of Blender? I can't even find it in *Preferences > Add-ons*.

Is it normal? And if it isn't normal, could someone explain how to get in back?

Answer (score 3):

Blenderkit requires a different version of the Add-on for 3.0.  Go to their website and [download](https://www.blenderkit.com/get-blenderkit/) and install the 3.0 version in your 3.0 installation.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution might be found @:

https://www.blenderkit.com/docs/add-on-troubleshooting/

What the page said is:

1-"First check if you have a firewall active, and try the connection with firewall switched off. If it's the firewall, try to whitelist Blender and/or Python.exe"

Translated into English this means go to your firewall setting and where it says 'add a program' or maybe 'allow exception', add Blender to the list of accepted programs. And I have to say this didn't do anything to fix the Blenderkit problem for me.

2-"If it wasn't the firewall, you can try proxy settings: First try setting NONE option for Proxy settings in BlenderKit add-on. This might help especially if you have VPN/Proxy on your system."

Go to Preferences/Addons, find Blenderkit and click on the little white arrow which unfurls a lot of options. Go to proxy and select 'none'. This made all the difference in the world for me. Hope it does for you too!

Answer (score 0):

BlenderKit as a user model library was unable to meet Blender's requirement that community add-ons should not access online resources. Because of that the BlenderKit add-on was removed from the set of pre-installed addons which ships with the Blender 3.x. That is the reason why you cannot by default find the BlenderKit in the Blender 3.x anymore.

You have to install the BlenderKit before using it in Blender 3.0, one possibility if to download it from official page: https://www.blenderkit.com/get-blenderkit/, the other options is to download the relase .zip file from project's releases page on Github: https://github.com/BlenderKit/blenderkit/releases.